# How do I add a reference for an assembly using c#

Tags: c#, project

I am programming an application in visual studio 2010 and i want to add a library to references using c# ,so i will add the using library and the invocation in file of a business class

```
public void addreference()
{

//needed code
}

public addInvocation()
{


//write in the file of business class
}
```

**it is like select add reference using the mouse but i am wishing use c# to do it**
how can i do it ?

---

**Critical solution**
i tried to use the solution but i found a problem , i instantiated successfully the class of the library but i  can not use their methods

first i created an Interface called Interface1
second i created a class called Classe1
then I generated the .dll

**The code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
  public   interface Interface1
    {

         int add();
         int sub();
    }


  public class Class1 : Interface1
  {
      Class1()
      {

      }


      #region Interface1 Members

      public int add()
      {
          return 10;
      }

      public int sub()
      {
          return -10;
      }

      #endregion
  }
}
```

---

the i tied to instantiate the class1
**the code**

```
 string relative = "ClassLibrary1.dll";
 string absolute = Path.GetFullPath(relative);

Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(absolute);
System.Type assemblytype = assembly.GetType("ClassLibrary1.Class1");

object a = assembly.CreateInstance("ClassLibrary1.Class1", false,           BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null,null,null, null);
```

---

Now i wish invoke the method add how can i do it

Comment: Right click on your project and select Add Reference.  Choose the library you wish to add from there.  Make sure you include the namespace of the library you are using.

Comment: no i am try to do that using c# code

Comment: do you want to reference an assembly at design time or do you want to load it dynamically at runtime? (in other words, do you know which assembly will need to be loaded before the code runs?)

Comment: Not a duplicate of that one really. You can load assemblies at run-time using reflection: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32828/Using-Reflection-to-load-unreferenced-assemblies-a

Comment: @LithuT.V: No, that's adding a reference at design time, not in code.

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 at runtime

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=reference+dll+runtime+%5BC%23%5D

Comment: have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/system.reflection.assembly.load.aspx

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad sorry and i will delete it

Comment: @Ammaedragas: You don't need to delete your question. Once enough people agree this is a duplicate then a link from this one to that will be created so anyone finding this question will get answers by looking at the other one.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett in the solution proposed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751844/how-to-reference-a-dll-on-runtime what is the PluginLoader

Comment: @Ammaedragas: Answered in the other answer's comments.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett new changes

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 new changes

Comment: @DarrenDavies new changes

Comment: as long as your interface is located in an assembly that is referenced at compile time, you could simply cast your object a to that interface ... if it's also part of the late loaded assembly you can use reflection to get the MethodInfo and call it that way

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 not resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = Activator.CreateInstance(assemblytype, argtoppass);
System.Type type = a.GetType();
if (type != null)
{
  string methodName = "methodname";
  MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(methodName);
  object resultpath = methodInfo.Invoke(a, argtoppass);
  res = (string)resultpath;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reflection seems the obvious option. Start with

```
foreach (FileInfo dllFile in exeLocation.GetFiles("*.dll"))
{

    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dllFile.FullName);

        ...
```

then:

```
Type[] exportedTypes = assembly.GetExportedTypes();
foreach (Type exportedType in exportedTypes)
{
    //look at each instantiable class in the assembly
    if (!exportedType.IsClass || exportedType.IsAbstract)
    {
        continue;
    }

//get the interfaces implemented by this class
Type[] interfaces = exportedType.GetInterfaces();
foreach (Type interfaceType in interfaces)
{
    //if it implements IMyPlugInterface then we want it
    if (interfaceType == typeof(IMyPlugInterface))
    {
        concretePlugIn = exportedType;
        break;
    }
}
```

finally

```
IMyPlugInterface myPlugInterface = (IMyPlugInterface) Activator.CreateInstance(concretePlugIn);
```

...or something like that. It won't compile but yet get the jist.

Comment: This doesn't really help. All that does is get file information about the assembly that's currently running. He wants to run one that isn't added.

Comment: Updated, I was talking to somebody else at the same time and cut'n'pasted the wrong code!

Comment: That's the second part covered (getting types from a reflection so he can use them), but how does he load the assembly from a file that's not already referenced?