# Could not load dll from class library project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dll, dependencies

I am using this library [WPFLocalizationExtension](https://github.com/SeriousM/WPFLocalizationExtension?lipi=urn%3Ali%3Apage%3Ad_flagship3_profile_view_base%3BLPFAAA29SiWF71pisIAy2w%3D%3D) to localize my WPF Application and **it works fine**.

But, I need to change the output type of my application to **Class library**.

After changing the properties and adapting the App.xaml, my class library compiles. However, when I call the dll from another application, the code throws a XamlParseException in the first xaml that uses the library. The error says:

*A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'WPFLocalizeExtension, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

If I add to the main App a reference to WPFLocalizationExtension it works fine. The problem is that I am developing a Plugin, so I actually don't have access to the main Application. Is there any way to add to the main App a reference to WPFLocalizationExtension from the plugin?

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Does the app having the issue have a reference to `WPFLocalizeExtension`?

Comment: I don't have access to the main App since I am developing a plugin (I will update this info to the question). Is there a way to add a reference to the main app from the Plugin?

Comment: Have a look at this answer [How to reference a DLL on runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5751934/2084193)

Comment: thanks @BassemAkl. That worked. If you want to write it as an answer I will mark it as the valid one.

Comment: @chincheta73, glad it worked. I'm not the owner of the original answer, and it just a link that I posted. So, it would not be a typical answer by StackOverflow's standards.