# WPF ToastNotifications from wpf class library does not load Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, notifications, resources

I am developing a plugin and I want to use this notification toast library from nuget: [Toast Notifications](https://github.com/raflop/ToastNotifications)

One of the steps I have to do to setup the Toast Notifications library is this:

**2 Import ToastNotifications.Messages theme in App.xaml**

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ToastNotifications.Messages;component/Themes/Default.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

However, I don't have an Application file since I am developing a class library. I have added the resourcer Dictionary to the UserControl that is creating the notifications. Like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ToastNotifications.Messages;component/Themes/Default.xaml" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

However, when I run the App I've got this exception:

*{System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception. ---> System.Exception: Cannot find resource named 'InformationIcon'. Resource names are case sensitive.*

But InformationIcon is an image inside the ToastNotifications library. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where and how are you creating the Notifier object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the main application that uses your plugin does not have a reference to the nuget package. So, you have two methods to solve this:

1. If you have access to the main application's project add the nuget lib to it.
2. If you do not. You have to load the assembly dynamically at runtime. Here is a good solution [How to reference a DLL on runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5751934/2084193)

> It searches through dlls in a given directory and finds classes that implement a particular interface. Below is the class I used to do this:

```
public class PlugInFactory<T>
{
    public T CreatePlugin(string path)
    {
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll"))
        {
            foreach (Type assemblyType in Assembly.LoadFrom(file).GetTypes())
            {
                Type interfaceType = assemblyType.GetInterface(typeof(T).FullName);

                if (interfaceType != null)
                {
                    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyType);
                }
            }
        }

        return default(T);
    }
}
```

All you have to do is initialize this class with something like this:

```
 PlugInFactory<InterfaceToSearchFor> loader = new PlugInFactory<InterfaceToSearchFor>();
     InterfaceToSearchFor instanceOfInterface = loader.CreatePlugin(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```