# Platform-dependent compilation of C# DLL

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, platform

I'm trying to set up a bunch of managed C# dlls to work inside Unity3D, but I'm struggling to get that done:

Imagine having C# managed Platform.dll for platform A and Platform.dll for platform B.

Now I want to build a C# managed dll, say Core.dll, that depends on Platform.dll, but does itself not have any Platform-dependent code in it. I thought that it should be possible to build a single managed C# dll, which looks up the right Platform.dll at runtime (given that only one of the Platform.dlls is enabled).

Is this possible and if yes how? Or do I have to stick with different Core.dlls which are again platform-dependent, because the underlying Platform.dll is?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5751844/11683?

Comment: ok, let me clarify the question: if Core.dll depends on Platform.dll (and I have more than one Platform.dll), do I need to build multiple Core.dlls (which I want to avoid) or is a single Core.dll sufficient (in terms of finding the right entry points on the underlying DLLs)?

Answer (score 0):

If you setup your dlls in Unity correctly (i.e. in-/exclude them for the relevant platforms), Unity should only include one Platform.dll into the build. If Core.dll doesn't use any interface that is only present in a subset of your Platform.dlls, it should work fine. Otherwise you'll get an exception when trying to build the Unity project for any platform where the respective Platform.dll is incompatible with the Core.dll.

Comment: yes, that include/exclude is what I already got right, but just to make sure: it means that even if the Core.dll is linked against Platform.dll from platform A at compile time, it should be able to refer to the Platform.dll from platform B later when building the respective project for Platform B - there are no hardcoded entry points for functions coded into it that differ between Platform.dll for A and B...

Comment: AFAIK, Unity links dlls when the player is built. You need one of the Platform.dlls when you compile the Core.dll, but the linking to the respective platform-specific dll Unity should do for you when you build for that platform. Don't know if that is also true for unmanaged dlls, but managed code _should_ "just work".

Comment: Hi, ok, that might work for building a platform. What about the Editor? I just tried to go with a platform-independent Core.dll and platform-dependent Platform.dlls. Although it is set to reference the right Platform.dll (OSX in my case), it gives me something like 

MissingMethodException: Method 'getDeviceInfo' not found. DeviceChecker+<Awake>c__async0.MoveNext () (at <b9d118ce5d6543f1bc471d71b2a369a3>:0)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.

so it does not work for the Editor environment...